# Redirect DNS-Queries in Samba4 AD of local domain

Tags: active-directory, ubuntu-14.04, samba4

I am running an Ubuntu 14.04 Samba4 AD Server and I control my networks DNS via a different server. I am using the samba version served by ubuntu which is 4.1.6.

Is it possible to configure the samba4 internal dns, so it relays querys even to its own domain to another server?

As an example:

Server *AD* (IP 192.168.0.5) runs the Samba4 AD has the following setup:

*/etc/resolv.conf*

`nameserver 127.0.0.1
search example.org`

*/etc/samba/smb.conf*
`[global]
 workgroup = EXAMPLE
 REALM = EXAMPLE.ORG
 netbios name = AD
 server role = active directory domain controller
 dns forwarder = 192.168.0.1`

And the Server *DNS* (IP 192.168.0.1) is a DNS-Server running and managing the rest of the domain. This DNS Server is provided by my local datacenter and so out of my hand. The *AD* shall know nothing about the other Computers running within *example.org.* but the moment I query for *foo.example.org* the Query should be relayed by *AD* to *DNS*.

My current situation is that the *AD* only relays querys different than the domain *example.org.*. How is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Is your other DNS (192.168.0.1) *Bind*-based? What is exact Samba version? There was an integration module for Bind AFAIR in Samba 4.0 (not sure about 4.1). This may allow for a greater control over hosts.

Comment: I am not the administrator of the other DNS, its distributed by our local datacenter. So the server is not out of my reach. The samba version I am using is 4.1.6. I'll update the question in that matter, thanks for asking!

Comment: Provided that, I can think of no other solution than using different domain name for Samba (or a subdomain - that seems close to what you're trying to do).